# Get links from ::before ::after using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrap a [website](https://www.ossiam.com/EN/) using Selenium in Python in order to extract few links.
But for some of the tags, I am not able to find the links. When I inspect element for these links, it points me to `::before` and `::after`. One way to do this is to click on it which opens a new window and get the link from the new window. But this solutions is quite slow. Can someone help me know how can I fetch these links directly from this page?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the links you are trying to extract are not statically stored inside the `i` elements you see there. These links are dynamically generated by some `JavaScripts` running on that page.
So, the answer is "No", you can not extract there links from that page without human-like iterating elements of that page.